# What does echo *?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, echo

Recently I was writing a bash-script and added a line:

```
$ echo *
```

and got an output of file names and directory names. 
What is the context of this list (just out of curiosity)?

Comment: Please search the site, this question was asked many times before.

Comment: I tried to couldn't find it. Can you provide a link? Thanks!

Comment: @cuonglm I'm sure it has but there's no ([working](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249848/search-using-symbols-is-broken), [discoverable](http://data.stackexchange.com/)) way to search for punctuation here.

Comment: @Gilles: yeap, I mean trying to search but not limited to the site search engine. I myself often use Google, although it does not support punctuation, too. Something like `Gilles + echo + asterisk site: unix.stackexchange.com` would give me some interesting links